# Перевод кода из Pascal в C++

Tags: c++, pascal

Помогите перевести код на С++

```
var d1, d2, d3, k, n: integer;
begin
    writeln('Введите число n, с которым будем сравнивать сумму цифр числа');
    readln(n);
    k := 0;
    {d1 – левая, d2 – средняя, d3 – правая цифры числа}
    for d1 := 1 to 9 do
        for d2 := 0 to 9 do
            for d3 := 0 to 9 do
                if (d1 + d2 + d3 = n) then
                begin
                    k := k + 1;
                    write(d1, d2, d3, ' ');
                end;
    writeln('Количество искомых чисел равно –', k);
end.
```

Comment: @amora, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Спасибо за совет)

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int d1, d2, d3, k, n;
    printf("Введите число n, с которым будем сравнивать сумму цифр числа\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    k = 0;
    for (d1 = 1; d1 <= 9; ++d1)
    ...
    ...
    if (d1 + d2 + d3 == n) {
        k += 1;
        printf("%d%d%d ", d1, d2, d3)
    }
    ...
}
```

Что вставить вместо троеточий, думаю, разберётесь.